# How to register an interrupt handler for the ARM Generic Timer from a kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, arm, interrupt

I am currently trying to register a custom handler for one of the timers of the Generic Timer on my Raspberry Pi 5 and unfortunately cannot get it to work.

So what I've done so far is to look into the device tree for the timer entry, where 4 interrupts are mentioned, namely the PPIs 10, 11, 13 and 14:

```
timer {
        compatible = "arm,armv8-timer";
        interrupts = <GIC_PPI 13 (GIC_CPU_MASK_SIMPLE(4) |
                      IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW)>,
                 <GIC_PPI 14 (GIC_CPU_MASK_SIMPLE(4) |
                      IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW)>,
                 <GIC_PPI 11 (GIC_CPU_MASK_SIMPLE(4) |
                      IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW)>,
                 <GIC_PPI 10 (GIC_CPU_MASK_SIMPLE(4) |
                      IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW)>;
        /* This only applies to the ARMv7 stub */
        arm,cpu-registers-not-fw-configured;
    };
```

Looking at `/proc/interrupts`, it seems like of those interrupts, 10 does not yet have a handler installed:

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
  9:          0          0          0          0     GICv2  25 Level     vgic
 11:          0          0          0          0     GICv2  30 Level     kvm guest ptimer
 12:          0          0          0          0     GICv2  27 Level     kvm guest vtimer
 13:       4018       9245       1668       9893     GICv2  26 Level     arch_timer
 14:       1147          0          0          0     GICv2  65 Level     107c013880.mailbox
 15:          5          0          0          0     GICv2 153 Level     uart-pl011
...
```

(Also, I wonder where the "kvm guest vtimer" comes from, if it wasn't mentioned in the device tree. Does anyone know?)

With this knowledge, I now inserted the following simple kernel module:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

DEFINE_PER_CPU(int, dev_id);

irqreturn_t test_handler(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
        int this_cpu = smp_processor_id();

        printk("CPU %i received interrupt!\n", this_cpu);

        return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

int test_init(void)
{
        u64 ctl = 0, cval = 0, tval = 0;
        int err = 0, cpu = 0;

        cpu = get_cpu();
        printk("CPU: %i\n", cpu);

        err = request_percpu_irq(10, test_handler, "test_module", &dev_id);
        printk("request_percpu_irq() err: %i\n", err);

        ctl = read_sysreg(CNTHP_CTL_EL2);
        cval = read_sysreg(CNTHP_CVAL_EL2);
        tval = read_sysreg(CNTHP_TVAL_EL2);
        printk("CNTHP_CTL_EL2: %llu\n", ctl);
        printk("CNTHP_CVAL_EL2: %llu\n", cval);
        printk("CNTHP_TVAL_EL2: %llu\n", tval);

        write_sysreg(1000, CNTHP_TVAL_EL2);

        cval = read_sysreg(CNTHP_CVAL_EL2);
        tval = read_sysreg(CNTHP_TVAL_EL2);
        printk("CNTHP_CVAL_EL2: %llu\n", cval);
        printk("CNTHP_TVAL_EL2: %llu\n", tval);

        put_cpu();

        return 0;
}

void test_exit(void)
{
        free_percpu_irq(10, &dev_id);
}

module_init(test_init);
module_exit(test_exit);
```

Looking at `/proc/interrupts` again, my handler seems to have been correctly registered:

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
  9:          0          0          0          0     GICv2  25 Level     vgic
 10:          0          0          0          0     GICv2  29 Level     test_module
 11:          0          0          0          0     GICv2  30 Level     kvm guest ptimer
 12:          0          0          0          0     GICv2  27 Level     kvm guest vtimer
 13:       2597       1798       3172       1910     GICv2  26 Level     arch_timer
 14:        249          0          0          0     GICv2  65 Level     107c013880.mailbox
 15:          5          0          0          0     GICv2 153 Level     uart-pl011
...
```

But what I also tried to do in the code is to generate an interrupt to trigger my new handler, and this unfortunately didn't work. According to the Generic Timer reference, the interrupt number 10 (or 26 if you add the PPI offset of 16) should be associated with the `Non-secure EL2 Physical Timer`, for which the associated system registers have the prefix `CNTHP` and the suffix `EL2`.

Here are the associated dmesg entries, which show that the configuration of the timer through the system registers seems to have worked. Also interrupt generation should be enabled according to `CNTHP_CTL_EL2`:

```
[   26.007926] test: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   26.008154] CPU: 3
[   26.008167] request_percpu_irq() err: 0
[   26.008169] CNTHP_CTL_EL2: 1
[   26.008172] CNTHP_CVAL_EL2: 1409277728
[   26.008174] CNTHP_TVAL_EL2: 185726
[   26.008177] CNTHP_CVAL_EL2: 1409093405
[   26.008179] CNTHP_TVAL_EL2: 998
```

But the printout inside `test_handler()` is missing, so the interrupt seems to not have reached my handler. And this is where I've unfortunately been stuck for a while now.

So how can you register an interrupt handler for the ARM Generic Timer from a linux kernel module? (And why doesn't it work my way?)

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=234418 It has lots of info and some sample code. You might want to post there too and, if you do, please add the kernel version you are using.